# d3.js : Generating axis ticks for ordinal values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use ordinal scale in x-axis with names as values.

```
let xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(['Tony', 'Jessica', 'Andrew', 'Emily', 'Richard'])
            .range([0, bodyWidth]);

        
 container.append('g')
       .style('transform', 'translate(0px, 200px)')
       .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
       .tickFormat(clients, (d)=> d + ' position')
       .tickValues( clients.map(d => d.name) );
```

But I am getting error:

> TypeError: container.append(...).style(...).call(...).tickFormat is
> not a function.

I am using d3.js V5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues.

First, you have `.tickFormat` being called on the return of the `.call` and not the `.axisBottom` chain.  This is why you get that it's not a function because `.call` will not return the axis.

Second, `.tickFormat` takes a single argument which is a function to be called when creating each axis tick.  You are passing it data and as accessor function.  Each domain value will be passed to the `.tickFormat` function.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="800"></svg>
  <script>
    let container = d3.select('svg');

    let xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(['Tony', 'Jessica', 'Andrew', 'Emily', 'Richard'])
      .range([0, 100, 200, 300, 400]);

    container.append('g')
      .style('transform', 'translate(100px, 0px)')
      .call(
        d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
          console.log(d + ' position');
          return d + ' position';
        })
      );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Making suggested changes has removed the error, but the values on x-axis are not displayed properly. they are clustered at both ends of the x-axis.

Comment: @SouravKumar, from the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#ordinal_range) -- `The first element in the domain will be mapped to the first element in range, the second domain value to the second range value, and so on. If there are fewer elements in the range than in the domain, the scale will reuse values from the start of the range.`  See updated snippet above.

Comment: BTW, for an axis you probably want to use band scale or a point scale.